# How do you know what focal lengths to use in a 3 lens terrestrial/Galilean telescope?

Tags: geometric-optics, lenses, telescopes

I'm trying to make a telescope with three converging lenses but can't figure out what my middle, erecting, lens' focal length should be.

Right now I'm using a 200mm objective lens and a 25mm eyepiece lens. Is there a certain focal length I have to use determined by the other two or can I use any focal length so long as it's in the right spot in the telescope?

If I can use any focal length how does that affect the magnification?

Comment: This may be better suited to [astronomy.se]. I see you're already a member.

Comment: Read [Section 15. Constructing a terrestrial telescope](http://irpoyser.co.uk/how-to-build-a-telescope/) where relay lenses are discussed in some detail.